# Qual seria o equivalente ao do while no python?

Tags: python, do-while

Qual seria o "do while" do python?

Grato!

Answer (score 1):

Não existe "do while" em Python, existem formas de fazer algo muito semelhante, utilizando das opções já existentes na linguagem.

Exemplo:

```
condition = True
while condition:
    # Corpo do laço
    condition = teste_laco_condicao()
```

> Esse exemplo foi baseado na resposta do powderflask

Existem outras formas de fazer, no link abaixo tem mais alguns exemplos, essa pergunta foi feita em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python